# ExtJs: Layout trying to adjust axis of Chart, but it's DOM config is undefined. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I've got a very irritating problem where I have 3 charts in a collapsed panel, and (sometimes!) when I expand this panel it fails to find the DOM config of the axes of first chart. The remaining charts render properly.

Unfortunately this bug cannot be consistently reproduced (I think this has to do with varying layout times?) and I haven't been able to create a minimal code example to showcase it either. What I do have is all the debugging information I could gather.

Would someone be interested in helping be debug this? This is my first extjs/javascript project and this goes beyond my knowledge to be honest. If any extra information could help please feel free to ask!

[image]
[image]
[image]
EDIT: As suggested here is the code for the component itself. It is called from a main view in collapsed state. The error occurs once this component is expanded:

```
Ext.define("NewApp.view.stationView.stationView",{
extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
alias: 'widget.stationView',
requires: [
    "NewApp.view.stationView.stationViewController"
],

controller: "stationview-stationview",

layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},

items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    flex: 1,
    items:[{
        xtype: 'cartesian',
        reference: 'AverageDuration',
        insetPadding: 10,
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'chartitemevents'
        },
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric',
            position: 'left',
            renderer: 'secondsToTimeAxis',
            grid: true
        },{
            type: 'category',
            position: 'bottom'
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'bar',
            xField: 'Name',
            yField: 'Average',
            label: {
                field: 'Average',
                display: 'insideEnd',
                orientation: 'horizontal',
                renderer: 'secondsToTimeLabel'
            }
        },{
            type: 'bar',
            xField: 'Name',
            yField: 'Estimate',
            animation: {
                duration: 0
            },
            renderer: 'EstimateRenderer'
        }],
        listeners: {
            itemclick: 'changeStore'
        },
        flex: 1
    },{
        xtype: 'cartesian',
        reference: 'Boxplot',
        insetPadding: 10,
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric',
            position: 'left',
            title: 'Frequency'
        },{
            type: 'category',
            position: 'bottom',
            renderer: 'secondsToTimeAxis',
            title: 'Duration'
        }],
        series: {
            type: 'bar',
            colors: ['rgb(52,73,94)'],
            xField: 'binStart',
            yField: 'binCount'
        },
        flex: 1
    }]
},{
        xtype: 'cartesian',
        reference: 'ControlChart',
        insetPadding: 10,
        height: '100%',
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric',
            position: 'left',
            renderer: 'secondsToTimeAxis',
            grid: true
        },{
            type: 'category',
            position: 'bottom',
            title: 'Main ID'
        }],
        series: {
            type: 'line',
            colors: ['rgb(52,151,219)'],
            xField: 'JointID',
            yField: 'Duration',
            marker: {
                radius: 4
            },
            tooltip: {
                trackMouse: true,
                showDelay: 0,
                dismissDelay: 0,
                hideDelay: 0,
                renderer: 'ControlChartTooltip'
            }
        },
        flex: 1
    }],

listeners: {
    stationClicked: 'stationClicked'
}
```

});

This component is called from my main view by the following:

```
{
    xtype: 'stationView',
    flex: 6,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    id: 'stationView',
    collapsible: true,
    collapsed: true,
    animCollapse: false,
    collapseDirection: 'bottom',
    listeners: {
        expand: function() {
           Ext.getCmp('firingLineViewExpanded').hide()
           Ext.getCmp('firingLineView').show()
        },
        collapse: function() {
           Ext.getCmp('firingLineView').hide()
           Ext.getCmp('firingLineViewExpanded').show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.  Post the relevant sections required to reproduce your problem instead - you also have a better chance at a response if you do the leg work and [create a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com).

Comment: I added the component part of my code, which is where the error comes from in my case. I'll try and make a fiddle today to expose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code, it's really difficult to give you a straight answer.

However, I see in your second picture where the script throws an error -- clearly `dom` is undefined (or at least null), so I'd first try wrapping that block of code in a conditional statement:

```
dom = cavases[k].dom;

if (dom) {
    //...
}
```

That should at least get you past the initial error.

(EDIT: also, you might check against the `rendered` property of the component)

Otherwise, you're going to have to find a way to force the component to render while collapsed/hidden. Components defined as "collapsed" or "hidden" are lazy-rendered by default to speed up your application.

Comment: I'll have a chance to look at it again on Monday, thank you for having a look at my problem! What do you mean by "check against render property"? Suspend layout of charts until the panel has been rendered?

Comment: Oh and the code you quoted is actually in the sencha source code of canvas.js. Is it wise/possible to alter that?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: False alarm, bug is still present. It just took about 20 refreshes to happen this time :(.

I think I've solved it. The panel which wasn't rendering properly was sharing an hbox layout container with another component, say component A. I had a triggered event on the first panel which on expand would replace component A with another one which had a different height. This change seems to have been the cause of the layout problems, and by change on 'expand' to 'beforeexpand' seems to have solved things.

EDIT2: It seems that the issue was caused by nested vbox/hbox layout, and this caused problems with the layouting of the first graph. I avoided this problem by using the border layout, which achieved the same layouting that was necessary.